# Proving that a solution involving the Laplacian is unique.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, proof-verification, laplacian

I've been asked the following question;

> If $u$ is a solution of $\nabla^2u = p(x)u$, for $x \in D$, and $\nabla u \cdot n = g(x)$, for $x \in \partial D$, show that $u$ is unique.

So, to begin, I considered two possible solutions, $u_{(1)}$ and $u_{(2)}$. Then, I have the following;

$$\nabla^2 u_{(1)} = p(x) u_{(1)}$$
$$\nabla^2 u_{(2)} = p(x) u_{(2)}$$
$$\nabla u_{(1)} \cdot n = g(x)$$
$$\nabla u_{(2)} \cdot n = g(x)$$

Then, I did the following;

$$u_{(1)} \nabla^2 u_{(2)} = u_{(1)} p(x) u_{(2)} = p(x) u_{(1)}u_{(2)}$$
$$u_{(2)} \nabla^2 u_{(1)} = u_{(2)} p(x) u_{(1)} = p(x) u_{(1)}u_{(2)}$$

Then, I took the difference of these two results, and integrated both sides over the given domain, $D$;

$$\int_D (u_{(1)} \nabla^2 u_{(2)} - u_{(2)} \nabla^2 u_{(1)}) dx = \int_D ( p(x) u_{(1)}u_{(2)} - p(x) u_{(1)}u_{(2)}) dx$$
$$\implies \int_{\partial D}(u_{(1)}\nabla u_{(2)} - u_{(2)} \nabla u_{(1)})\cdot n dS = 0$$
$$\implies \int_{\partial D} (u_{(1)}g(x) - u_{(2)}g(x))dS = 0$$
$$\implies \int_{\partial D} g(x) (u_{(1)} - u_{(2)}) dS = 0$$

Now, this was just a whole bunch of mucking around with Green's Identities and integrands, but I'm a bit stuck at this point. Is it appropriate for me to divide both sides by the $g(x)$ term?? And even then, I could say that the surface integral of $u_{(1)}$ is equal to the surface integral of $u_{(2)}$, but does that really help me??

I'm just a bit unsure as to which direction I should be taking this proof. Any input would be great. :)

Comment: It seems to me that, if $v=u_{(1)}-u_{(2)}$, $v$ should solve the homogeneous problem $\nabla^2 v=p(x)v$ with $\nabla v\cdot n=0$ on the boundary. You need to prove that $v=0$. So $g$ should not make any appearance in your proof.

Comment: Ah, I'll give that a go!!

Comment: I think I have it now, but just to confirm, you get $\nabla v \cdot n = 0$ through $\nabla (u_{(1)} - u_{(2)}) \cdot n = g(x) - g(x) = 0$, yes??

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: Too easy, thank you very much, I was trying to overcomplicate the situation.

Comment: Yes, that is known to happen. You're welcome. Say, why don't you write up what you learned as an answer, then accept it? That way, the question won't remain on file as unanswered. I am too lazy to do it myself. 8-)

Answer (score 0):

By setting up $v$ as outlined in the comments, we have the following system;
$\nabla^2 v = p(x)v$, $\nabla v \cdot n = 0$.

From this, it can be shown quite easily that $v = 0$ for all $x$ in and on the domain, $D$.

Then, it's fairly easy to see that $v = 0 \implies u_{(1)}-u_{(2)}=0 \implies u_{(1)} = u_{(2)}$, as required!!